# How to Turn Off Output Window of VS Code (for Angular Language Service)?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

`Output Window` of Visual Studio Code opens on its own while I'm typing or just clicking Angular code I'm working on and it's very disturbing.

Angular Language Service plug-in is installed I don't see any settings for it.

**Update**

I've opened an [issue on Github repo](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/128).

Comment: This issue has been there for a while. It started happening after an update. I guess the VS Code team is working on this and this should be gone with the next update. 
I know it is annoying, for time being i just dragged the top of the Output Window and slide it down to the minimum height. This way the window is always open, but no more a distraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be fixed with release version 0.1.7

Comment: I have 0.1.7 and it still crashes

Comment: @Matt yes, as of today I have the same problem again, it was fine for last few weeks. Un-freakin' believable.

Comment: Yes, this is not fixed sadly--also extremely annoying.

Answer (score 0):

**Go to File > Preferences > Settings**

Add this line in the User Settings :

```
"tslint.enable": false
```